# moving up problem in custom table view cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, scroll

I am using custom table view cell to show to table view

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier 
{
if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) 
{
     m_mail_status = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(295, 10, 18, 18)];
    [self addSubview:m_mail_status];

    m_subject = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 270, 37)];
    UIFont* font = m_subject.font;

    m_subject.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:font.pointSize];

    //m_subject.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17];
    [self addSubview:m_subject];

    m_from = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 37, 200, 15)];
    m_from.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    [self addSubview:m_from];

    m_date = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(180, 37, 140, 15)];
    m_date.textAlignment= UITextAlignmentRight;
    m_date.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    [self addSubview:m_date];




}
return self;
}
```

and my code in view controller,

```
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"ProductsCell";
InboxViewCell *cell = (InboxViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

//static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

// UITableViewCell *cell = nil;// [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
//cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"xx"] autorelease];


if(cell == nil) 
    cell = [[[InboxViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];


    cell.m_subject.text = [[inbox objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"subject"];
    cell.m_from.text = [[inbox objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"from"];
    cell.m_date.text = [[inbox objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"date"];

    if([[[inbox objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"**reservation_status**"] isEqualToString:@"1"])     
    {
    cell.m_mail_status.image =  [UIImage imageNamed:@"reservation_symbol.png"];
    }
```

It loads in proper manner when it first loads
The issue when i scroll down and move to up
all the image is shown it ignores the if statement result

Thanks in advance

Regards,
sathish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is that the cells are reused, you will want to reset that image in the else of your if.